# How to read Windows Event Message when EventLogProvider does not contain a message table

Tags: c, windows, winapi, dll

It seems that not all Windows event message expansion strings are  specified in the "EventMessageFile" registry values. For example, for "Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager" on Windows 2008 server, the EventMessageFile DLL  %SystemRoot%\system32\termsrv.dll" does not contain a message table:

[image: missing message table]

this means that FormatMessageW with the DLL handle set to termsrv.dll doesn't work :( Where can I get the correct message strings?

Comment: if you test call `FormatMessageW` with correct error value and arguments - you can view that it "work" - load `\<lang>-<sublung>\termsrv.dll.mui` via `LdrLoadAlternateResourceModuleEx` and got string from it

Comment: What are the correct arguments? I've used this: 
```
data = win32api.FormatMessageW(win32con.FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE,
                                           dllHandle, event.EventID, LANGID, event.StringInserts)
            
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows PE files with a [MUI resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319070(v=vs.85).aspx) store the language specific resources in a external PE file with a .MUI extension. In this case the file would be `%SystemRoot%\system32\en-us\termsrv.dll.mui` for English resources.

Most Windows APIs automatically follow the MUI redirection when loading resources...